# Pulling computer names from .txt PowerShell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have done much research but have yet to find a successful solution, I am trying to pull computer names from a .txt, and get the error logs from each system. If I write each systems name out after `-ComputerName` it runs fine, but pulling from a .txt I get an error.

```
Get-Content "C:\Users\donovan.claxton\Desktop\PS\pc names.txt" | ForEach-Object {
    Get-EventLog -ComputerName $_ -Newest 50 -LogName System -EntryType Error |
        Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\donovan.claxton\Documents\Error logs\System Errors$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss')).csv"
}
```

```
Get-EventLog : The network path was not found.
At C:\Users\donovan.claxton\Documents\Powershell Scripts\eventlog system script.ps1:2 char:1
+ Get-EventLog -ComputerName $_ -Newest 50 -LogName System -EntryType E ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-EventLog], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetEventLogCommand
```

Comment: What's inside your file `pc names.txt`? Can you show a few lines?

Comment: as Olaf implied, you appear to either have a blank line in the file OR leading/trailing characters that are causing problems. so ... as Olaf asked ...would you please post the 1st few lines of the file?

Comment: To add to what others have said. Have you tried just seeing what you get in the console when you load the file?

Comment: In the pc names.txt file the system names are written as follows:

Comment: computer1, computer2, computer3, computer4, computer5 and so on

Comment: I have also loaded the file and checked the console and it is showing all of the pc names.

Comment: @SkaterCoderGamerDon - have you tried piping those values to `Format-Hex` to see if they have any unintended characters?

Comment: Try this (Get-Content <filepath>).Split(',').Trim() | Foreach-Object etc...   Your datafile has the names on one line separated by comma's and spaces in between. It's better to put every name on a separate line without spaces

Comment: so the file `pc names.txt` contains a comma separated list of computernames?

Comment: Please show the output of `Get-Content "C:\Users\donovan.claxton\Desktop\PS\pc names.txt" | ForEach-Object {"-$_-"}`.

Comment: This (Get-Content <filepath>).Split(',').Trim() resolved the issue for me, thank you for all the help everyone.